# Erlang: Finding my IP Address

Tags: erlang

I'm attempting to complete a Load Balancer / Login Server / Game Server setup using Redis for some parts. Load balancing is one of them. In my Redis load balancing instance I'm using ordered sets. The key is the application name, the members are the IP addresses of the game servers.

Herein lies my issue. I would like to use a public method within erlang. I cannot find anything that fits my needs. I'm wondering if I'm over looking something.

```
{ok, L} = inet:getif(),
IP = element(1, hd(L)),
```

Gives me what I'm looking for. I believe currently it's {192,168,0,14}. But the function is not "public."

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:listen(?PORT_LISTEN_GAME, [{active,once}, {reuseaddr, true}]),
{ok, {IP, _} = inet:sockname(Socket),
```

Gives me {0,0,0,0}. I've tried `inet:getaddr("owl")` which gives me {127,0,1,1}.

Am I limited to sending messages via TCP and using `inet:peername(Socket)`? Seems like a lot to get something so simple. All the different parts of my app are running on the same computer for testing. Is it going to give me back {127,0,0,1}? That wouldn't work. I need to send the IP back to the user (my mobile phone) so they can link up with the proper server. Loopback wouldn't do....

**Current Code**

I would like to thank all the responses. Yes, I noticed Lol4t0's comment just after the New Year. So I changed my code to reflect that. Posting this for the slow people like myself. I have to wrack my brain for a bit to get these things to click.

```
hd([Addr || {_, Opts} <- Addrs,
    {addr, Addr} <- Opts,
    {flags, Flags} <- Opts,
    lists:member(loopback,Flags) =/= true]).
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We've been successfully using this function to get the first non-local IPv4 address:

```
local_ip_v4() ->
    {ok, Addrs} = inet:getifaddrs(),
    hd([
         Addr || {_, Opts} <- Addrs, {addr, Addr} <- Opts,
         size(Addr) == 4, Addr =/= {127,0,0,1}
    ]).
```

It can of course be changed to return IPv6 as well if that is what you want.

Comment: I was looking into proplists but this is much preferred. I'm not too familiar with constructing lists in this manner. Thank you. I modified it slightly. Perhaps you might like this better. :)

What was happening to me was that it was grabbing the next (ipv6) loopback... although if I used your size constraint it wouldn't have happened.

Comment: hd([Addr || {IF, Opts} <- Addrs, {addr, Addr} <- Opts, IF =/= "lo"]).

Comment: @NolanRobidoux That can give you both IPv4 and IPv6 randomly and it doesn't take into account interfaces with names like `lo0` etc.

Comment: I guess anyway one uses it there will always be some tweaking. For me IDC if I get IPv4 or IPv6 as long as my phone can talk to my computer. :)

Comment: @NolanRobidoux, "What was happening to me was that it was grabbing the next (ipv6) loopback" You just need to check _flags_ instead of applying hacks.

Answer (score 2):

You should first understand that your host can have more than one unique IP address. In fact all `{0,0,0,0}`, `{127,0,0,1}` (hey! actually all 127.0.0.0/8 is your addresses) and `{192,168,0,14}` are all your valid IP addresses. Additionally if your host will have some other interfaces connected you'll get even more IP addresses. So you basically can't find a function that will get your *the* IP address you need.

Instead it is a well documented [function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#getifaddrs-0) in the `inet` module that will list interfaces each with its own IP address:

```
getifaddrs() -> {ok, Iflist} | {error, posix()}

Types:

Iflist = [{Ifname, [Ifopt]}]
Ifname = string()
Ifopt = {flag, [Flag]}
      | {addr, Addr}
      | {netmask, Netmask}
      | {broadaddr, Broadaddr}
      | {dstaddr, Dstaddr}
      | {hwaddr, Hwaddr}
Flag = up
     | broadcast
     | loopback
     | pointtopoint
     | running
     | multicast
Addr = Netmask = Broadaddr = Dstaddr = ip_address()
Hwaddr = [byte()]
```

Comment: Thanks. Should've kept going down the list on the online erlang manpages. I know each interface has an IP :) I just need a valid one to use that is unique (i.e. not any loopback) so my phone can talk to it and the game server instances can be rate limited properly. This fits the bill.

Comment: doesn't list my ipv6 though

Answer (score 0):

Using the getifaddr() function from OTP gives a detailed list of all interfaces available to the machine. The following solution should clear up a lot of confused newcomers to erlang as it stumped me too. This function is not optimized but is very readable and gives you your machines local IP4 address like the one you'd use at a LAN party:

```
 %Get the local IP4 address of this machine in the local network (LAN party address)
local_ip_v4() ->
  {ok, IntfList} = inet:getifaddrs(), %Get a list of all interfaces (Wifi, Lan, Internal loopback etc)

  %Filter this list to look for an interface that is "up and running" (has a connection) 
   SelectedInf = lists:foldl( fun(El, SelectedIf)->
                {InfName,InfOpts} = El,
                Flags = lists:keyfind(flags,1,InfOpts),
                case Flags of
                  {flags,[up,running]} ->
                    {InfName,InfOpts};
                  _->
                    SelectedIf
                end
                end,
                none,IntfList),

  io:format("~n INTERFACES: ~p ",[IntfList]),
  io:format("~n Selected INTERFACE: ~p ",[SelectedInf]),

  %Look through this interface's properties for the addresses, but only match one
  % that has 4 components in the tuple!
  {Sel_InfName,Sel_InfOpts} = SelectedInf,
  Address_I4 = lists:foldl( fun(El,Addr)->
                              case El of
                                {addr,{A,B,C,D}}->
                                  {A,B,C,D};
                                _->
                                  Addr
                              end
                            end, none, Sel_InfOpts),
  io:format("~n Selected INTERFACE IP4: ~p ~n",[Address_I4]),
  Address_I4.
```

Hope this helps :)