# Erlang: read ip address

Tags: erlang, erl

I'm trying to get my IP address using Erlang.

I found this example from here: [Erlang: Finding my IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984215/erlang-finding-my-ip-address)

```
local_ip_v4() ->
    {ok, Addrs} = inet:getifaddrs(),
    hd([Addr || {_, Opts} <- Addrs, {addr, Addr} <- Opts, size(Addr) == 4, Addr =/= {127,0,0,1}]).
```

But it returns a value like this: `{127,0,0,1}`

I want it to return a value like this: `"{127,0,0,1}"` with double quotes (`""`) because I want to use `re:replace` to change `,` to `.`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function returns the tuple because this is something that erlang code can handle natively. What you might want to do is transform this tuple to a string and then apply string operations. Details on how to do that can be found e.g. at [Convert erlang terms to string, or decode erlang binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423488/convert-erlang-terms-to-string-or-decode-erlang-binary)

Answer (score 14):

If you want to convert the IP address to a string, you can use the function [`inet:ntoa/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#ntoa-1):

```
> inet:ntoa({127, 0, 0, 1}).
"127.0.0.1"
```

As a bonus, it handles IPv6 addresses as well:

```
> inet:ntoa({0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}).
"::1"
```